# Get first occurrences of group in log

Tags: text-processing

I have a huge log that I intend to filter only to the first occurrence of each group. In the log "group" is everything after the timestamp in the first column.

See an example:

```
Mar 06 16:34:00.378;sample07;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
Mar 06 16:34:02.856;sample03;0.1.0-3af8c384;Y2XdtYN2of7JUc4b;
Mar 06 16:34:03.314;sample07;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
Mar 06 16:34:03.525;sample07;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
Mar 06 16:34:04.773;sample01;0.1.0-3af8c384;A6OZwO2e9wV6Z1PI;
Mar 06 16:34:04.997;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;9azoPOnrcabk8Lfv;
Mar 06 16:34:05.241;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;9azoPOnrcabk8Lfv;
Mar 06 16:34:06.546;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;9azoPOnrcabk8Lfv;
Mar 06 16:34:06.671;sample08;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
Mar 06 16:34:07.394;sample05;0.1.0-3af8c384;JJYhwRHyTMNKM2DI;
Mar 06 16:34:07.569;sample05;0.1.0-3af8c384;JJYhwRHyTMNKM2DI;
Mar 06 16:34:09.120;sample05;0.1.0-3af8c384;JJYhwRHyTMNKM2DI;
Mar 06 16:34:09.371;sample05;0.1.0-3af8c384;JJYhwRHyTMNKM2DI;
Mar 06 16:34:09.534;sample06;0.1.0-3af8c384;tasghviiAoMrPfaZ;
Mar 06 16:34:09.662;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;Y2XdtYN2of7JUc4b;
Mar 06 16:34:09.822;sample07;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
```

The expected result is:

```
Mar 06 16:34:00.378;sample07;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
Mar 06 16:34:02.856;sample03;0.1.0-3af8c384;Y2XdtYN2of7JUc4b;
Mar 06 16:34:04.773;sample01;0.1.0-3af8c384;A6OZwO2e9wV6Z1PI;
Mar 06 16:34:04.997;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;9azoPOnrcabk8Lfv;
Mar 06 16:34:06.671;sample08;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
Mar 06 16:34:07.394;sample05;0.1.0-3af8c384;JJYhwRHyTMNKM2DI;
Mar 06 16:34:09.534;sample06;0.1.0-3af8c384;tasghviiAoMrPfaZ;
Mar 06 16:34:09.662;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;Y2XdtYN2of7JUc4b;
```

I was able got the unique combinations without the timestamp:

```
cut -d";" -f2- small_log.log | sort | uniq
```

But how do I join it back to get the timestamp? I also don't think that `sort | uniq` will scale well to millions of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this in awk:

```
$ awk -F';' '++seen[$2$3$4]==1' file 
Mar 06 16:34:00.378;sample07;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
Mar 06 16:34:02.856;sample03;0.1.0-3af8c384;Y2XdtYN2of7JUc4b;
Mar 06 16:34:04.773;sample01;0.1.0-3af8c384;A6OZwO2e9wV6Z1PI;
Mar 06 16:34:04.997;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;9azoPOnrcabk8Lfv;
Mar 06 16:34:06.671;sample08;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
Mar 06 16:34:07.394;sample05;0.1.0-3af8c384;JJYhwRHyTMNKM2DI;
Mar 06 16:34:09.534;sample06;0.1.0-3af8c384;tasghviiAoMrPfaZ;
Mar 06 16:34:09.662;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;Y2XdtYN2of7JUc4b;
```

The default action in `awk` when something evaluates to true is to print the current line. The expression `++seen[$1$2}` makes the second and third fields the key in the associative array `seen`, and increases its value by one. Therefore, `++seen[$2$3$4]==1` will only be true the first time this combination of 2nd and 3rd field is seen.

It's basically a shorthand way of writing:

```
awk -F';' '{ 
             seen[$2$3$4]++; 
             if(seen[$2$3$4] == 1){
                print
             }
            }' file
```

Alternatively, you can also do it as you had attempted, with `sort`. You don't even need to `cut`, just tell `sort` to sort on fields 2 through 4 and return unique results:

```
$ sort -t';' -k2,4 -u file 
Mar 06 16:34:04.773;sample01;0.1.0-3af8c384;A6OZwO2e9wV6Z1PI;
Mar 06 16:34:02.856;sample03;0.1.0-3af8c384;Y2XdtYN2of7JUc4b;
Mar 06 16:34:04.997;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;9azoPOnrcabk8Lfv;
Mar 06 16:34:09.662;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;Y2XdtYN2of7JUc4b;
Mar 06 16:34:07.394;sample05;0.1.0-3af8c384;JJYhwRHyTMNKM2DI;
Mar 06 16:34:09.534;sample06;0.1.0-3af8c384;tasghviiAoMrPfaZ;
Mar 06 16:34:00.378;sample07;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
Mar 06 16:34:06.671;sample08;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
```

And if you need them sorted by timestamp, just pipe through `sort` again:

```
$ sort -t';' -k2,4 -u file  | sort
Mar 06 16:34:00.378;sample07;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
Mar 06 16:34:02.856;sample03;0.1.0-3af8c384;Y2XdtYN2of7JUc4b;
Mar 06 16:34:04.773;sample01;0.1.0-3af8c384;A6OZwO2e9wV6Z1PI;
Mar 06 16:34:04.997;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;9azoPOnrcabk8Lfv;
Mar 06 16:34:06.671;sample08;0.1.0-3af8c384;WXHXdaYrHcVQYvLR;
Mar 06 16:34:07.394;sample05;0.1.0-3af8c384;JJYhwRHyTMNKM2DI;
Mar 06 16:34:09.534;sample06;0.1.0-3af8c384;tasghviiAoMrPfaZ;
Mar 06 16:34:09.662;sample04;0.1.0-3af8c384;Y2XdtYN2of7JUc4b;
```